# Why i get a ModuleNotFoundError when i use pickle?

Tags: python-3.x

i wanna read a pkl file , but get a error, how do i slove it?

```py
import pickle
# pandas  1.5.0
f = open("1_cpg_input.pkl", 'rb')
data = pickle.load(f)
print(data)

data = pickle.load(f,)
```

the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.frame'
```

Answer (score 0):

It look like you are using a pandas dataframe...  so you might only need to add the `import pandas as pd` line at the top.

You can start from the beginning and replicate creating a pickle file and then reading it back to check you have everything set up correctly and that the pickle file is formed correctly.

This is example code that works:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'Name': ['Microsoft Corporation', 'Google, LLC', 'Tesla, Inc.',\
             'Apple Inc.', 'Netflix, Inc.'],
    'Symbol': ['MSFT', 'GOOG', 'TSLA', 'AAPL', 'NFLX'],
    'Industry': ['Tech', 'Tech', 'Automotive', 'Tech', 'Entertainment'],
    'Shares': [100, 50, 150, 200, 80]
}
# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# print dataframe
print(df)

# save dataframe as a pickle file
df.to_pickle('portfolio.pkl')

# read pickle file as dataframe
df2 = pd.read_pickle('portfolio.pkl')
# print the dataframe
print(df2)
```